# extract total HD memory and HD memory usage with linux command top

Tags: linux, bash, grep, disk

I'm looking forward to extract disk memory usage from top command using grep command an save it into a variable available for the bash interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... and I assume you failed to grep those part from `top`'s output without understanding why...

This happens to many users, the reason is that the `top` command has a somewhat unexpected output strategy. It does make sense, once you dig into it, but as said, unexpected:

By default, `top` does *not* write it's output to stdout which is the precondition so that you can grep through it's output. However if you take a look into it's man page (`man top`), then you will spot the `-b` flag you can use to invoke it such that it *does* write it's output to stdout. This enables you to process the output as you are used to under unixoid environments, for example by "grepping" parts of the output for further usage.

Together with the `-n` flag which allows you to limit the commands output to a single iteration (again: see the man page) you can construct a simple extraction command:

```
top -b -n 1|grep "KiB"
```

I think from here on you will find the way by yourself :-) Have fun!

Comment: Reading @Cyrus answer I just realize that I probably got it all wrong: my suggestion is about extracting information about memory usage. I " usage numbers. One usually calls that "disk space". Sorry for that. I guess my answer is worthless for you :-) As @Cyrus suggested, indeed the `df` and the `du` utilities are probably more suited for your task. Again: check their man pages...

Answer (score 1):

`top` provides no information about your hard disk usage.
Take a look at `df`.